# Mysql current time falls between two time field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `available_timings` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,

  `from_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_time` time DEFAULT NULL
 
); 



INSERT INTO `available_timings` (`id`, `from_time`, `to_time`) VALUES
(1, '15:11:00' , '17:15:00'),
(2, '15:11:00', '15:11:00'),
(3,  '09:00:00', '12:30:00'),
(4,  '15:40:00', '15:40:00'),
(5,'13:30:00', '17:15:00'),
(6,  '16:10:00', '16:10:00'),
(7,  '07:45:00', '11:45:00'),
(8, '19:00:00', '22:30:00'),
(9,   '16:14:00', '16:14:00'),
(10,   '09:30:00', '17:45:00'),
(11,  '10:30:00','15:15:00');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc9afe/2

I am trying to achieve whether the current time falls between `from time` and `to time` in `mysql`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `available_timings` 
WHERE curtime() >=`from_time` or curtime() <=`to_time`
```

i have searched many forum and also tried few queries but couldn't succeeded.

Can any one help me here to solve my problem

Thank you

Comment: between from time and to time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `available_timings` 
WHERE curtime() BETWEEN `from_time` AND `to_time`
```

Comment: Totally correct answer. Anyway: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @Barmer.now query looks simple but for me its not went of my mind.thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use `AND` instead of `OR`

```
WHERE curtime() >= `from_time` 
  AND curtime() <= `to_time`
```

You don't want any of these conditions to be true. You want both of them to be true.

Comment: @juergen.this works in php very well but fails in sql.any way thanks for the answer

Comment: That code is 100% SQL. It does not fail there. Must be something else.